# How can I use multiple basemaps with IPyLeaflet?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipyleaflet

In leaflet.js it is possible to have [multiple basemaps that show up in radio boxes at the top of LayerControl](http://bl.ocks.org/cccruzr/2be38431f91ff2adb9ded7c0e0950382):

[image: A leaflet LayerControl showing three layers each selectable with a radio box.]

With IPyLeaflet I can do `map.add_layer(tile_layer)`, but that is not the same as the leaflet example as the layer does not show up as a basemap layer in the LayerControl, and every basemap added this way will be loaded into the map and visible at the same time:

[image: LayerControl showing two layers, one has a radio box and one has a check box.]

How can I do this in IPyLeaflet?

Answer (score 1):

In IPyLeaflet, as of version 0.16.0, this can be achieved by setting the `base` property on the TileLayer object to `True`:

```py
from ipyleaflet import *

mapnik = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
mapnik.base = True
mapnik.name = 'Mapnik Layer'

toner = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.Stamen.Toner)
toner.base = True
toner.name = 'Toner Layer'

bzh = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.OpenStreetMap.BZH)
bzh.base = True
bzh.name = 'BZH layer'

m = Map(center=(52, 10), zoom=8, layers=[mapnik, toner, bzh])

m.add_control(LayersControl())

m
```

([Source](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/970))